# Facebook login without UI in Facebook SDK 4.x?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

In version 3.x of the SDK I there was a function:

> FBSession.openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI(Bool)

By setting the Bool to false it would use the stored session token to get a new access token on reopening the app. I used this in an auto login function.

It looked like this in 3.x:

```
if FBSession.openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI(false) {
    if let token = FBSession.activeSession()?.accessTokenData.accessToken {
        // Login to server with token
    }
}
```

But in the new SDK version 4.x I cant find any similar function, there is only a function which requires UI.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4.x SDK, you can use the `FBSDKAccessToken` class for this check and then either continue or have the user go through the Login flow.

Here is the [Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x#login) for 3.x to 4.x migration.

Comment: Yesy but I use openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI for autologin on app launch. FBSDKAccessToken only caches when logging in with UI and removes it on logout or app termination.